# printing hello world in assembly using msdn api

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, msdn

I'm starting to learn assembly language just today and I'm using masm. I tried to print hello world using msdn api

here's my code:

```
1 .386
2 .model flat, stdcall
3 option casemap :none
4
5 include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
6 include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
7 includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
8 includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
9
10 .data
11 stroutput db "Hello World",0
12
13 .code
14 main:
15      push stroutput
16      call printf                    ; print hello world
17      add esp, 4
18      end main
```

but I got an error:

> hello.asm(15) : error A2070: invalid instruction operands
>   hello.asm(16) : error A2006: undefined symbol : _printf

**EDIT** I tried to modified my code based on the suggestions:

```
.686
.model flat, stdcall

EXTERN printf : proc

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib    
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data
msgCaption db 'Try', 0

.code
Main:                      
push offset msgCaption  
call printf
push eax       

End Main
```

but still got an error:
hello.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf

Comment: Where do you think the definition of _printf will be?  (Obviously) you don't define it, and it's not in kernel32 or masm32.  Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29668361/2189500).

Comment: When you want to use the printf function you had to declare it extern: extern printf

Comment: `push stroutput` is incorrect since that is the same as `push [stroutput]` . It should have been `push offset stroutput`

Comment: you'll need `push OFFSET stroutput` to push the address instead of the data, since this is MASM syntax not NASM.  Also, you might need `call _printf`, or maybe not because apparently masm is prepending the leading underscore for you?  Anyway, `printf` is a C library function, not an WinAPI system call.  You won't find it in `kernel32.dll/lib`

Comment: Why the numbers at the start of each line?

Comment: @usr2564301 for the purpose of checking the error message

Comment: Again, `printf` is not in kernel32, it's in the C standard library not WinAPI.

Comment: @PeterCordes Even the msvcrt only has `_printf`, not `printf`.

Comment: @fuz: From the OP's error messages, it appears that `call printf` in the masm source is turning into a `_printf` symbol for the linker.  And if not, then I was talking about the C function name.  (I did already mention the possible issue with leading underscores in my earlier comment.)

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34210350/3512216. Did you mean "MASM32" instead of "msdn"? If so, please correct the title, text and  tags.